# Hide duplicate values in mysql view

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows

I would like to know if this scenario is possible in `mysql` view:

2 tables, `invoiceheader` and `invoicedetails`

In the `invoiceheader` table I have 2 records: `invoiceno = 1` and `invoiceno = 2`.
In the `invoice details` table I have 3 records:
`item, desc, cost`
001, paper, 25.95
002, pen, 15.99
003, keyboard, 259.51

When I join these 2 tables I get the following:

```
InvoiceNo, item, desc, value
row 1: 1, 001, paper, 25.95
row 2: 1, 002, pen, 15.99
row 3: 1, 003, keyboard, 259.51
row 4: 2, 001, paper, 25.95
row 5: 2, 003, keyboard, 259.51
```

Is it possible to only show `invoice no. 1` in row 1, but in row 2 and 3, do not show the invoice number again for that invoice, then the first record of invoice 2 again , but not the rest of invoice 2?
Like this:

```
row 1: 1, 001, paper, 25.95
row 2:    002, pen, 15.99
row 3:    003, keyboard, 259.51
row 4: 2, 001, paper, 25.95
row 5:    003, keyboard, 259.51
```

Comment: What you are asking seems impossible, but also is not necessary unless you want it to show this way in command line client. You can always adjust the results when you output them from your script.

Comment: It's not possible with any relational database that I know of but why do you need this in the first place? You can always do that when you will visualize this data.